# WebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString parse errors

Tags: swift, parsing, webkit, javascriptcore

When loading a script using WebView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString that contains syntax errors, the script is not loaded at all and no error is returned. I set up my WebView's context like this to report errors:

```
let context = view.mainFrame.javaScriptContext;

context.setObject(false, forKeyedSubscript: "JSError");
context.exceptionHandler = { context, exception in
  self.logIntern("JS Error: " + exception.toString());
  context.setObject(true, forKeyedSubscript: "JSError");
}
```

This reporting works nicely for runtime errors, but not parse errors. How can I know that parsing my script failed (maybe including parsing info, like error type and line number)?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal using `WebScriptDebugDelegate` private API ([first private header](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-6531.9/mac/WebView/WebScriptDebugDelegate.h)). You need to set your object as `scriptDebugDelegate` ([second private header](https://src.chromium.org/blink/branches/old/Safari-Den-branch/WebKit/WebView.subproj/WebViewPrivate.h)) for your `WebView` instance.

In script debug delegate you should implement following method: `- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView failedToParseSource:(NSString *)source baseLineNumber:(unsigned)lineNumber fromURL:(NSURL *)url withError:(NSError *)error forWebFrame:(WebFrame *)webFrame`. Other methods fro this protocol also look very promising.

I believe that answer in Objective-C is much better that nothing :)